# Identify component in 1970s vintage video game from photo

Tags: identification, components, vintage

Can anyone identify these two components, marked "SKY 4433" and "2.000000 K.D.S", respecitvely? Are they capacitors, crystals, or something else?
They are from a vintage 1970s ball-and-paddle-style video game (Parat Game by Technigraph) based around the AY-3-8500 chip.

[image: Gray component marked SKY 4433]
[image: Gray component marked "2.000000 K.D.S"]

Comment: I can't confirm this, but the fact they are placed in such close proximity to a pair of ceramic caps and a tuning cap suggests that they may be early crystal oscillators, probably 2MHz.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both are crystals. 4.433 MHz is for PAL subcarrier and 2.0 MHz for something else like CPU.

Comment: Great! Thanks!!